# Can't reinstall VLC

Tags: vlc

I use VLC a lot. And when 2.0 came out Ubuntu did not update to that version, the REPO had the older version even months later, So I added the daily repo:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu
and that worked for a while, after a few months later I received a 'Distribution upgrade'

and when I installed it, it removed VLC. when I tried to re-install it gave me a bunch of unmet dependency's, so I disabled the source, ran apt-get update, and tried to install the older VLC, that did not work either. I eventually found a web page, and it helped me get it working, and I was also able to get the 'Stable Daily' working too

But last night, I got another 'distro upgrade' and it uninstalled VLC again.
when I try to reinstall from daily I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: fonts-freefont-ttf but it is not installable
       Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.3+git20121005+r392-0~r42~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore5 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.3+git20121005+r392-0~r42~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.0.3+git20121005+r392-0~r42~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

and from the default source:

```
vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore5 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-pulse : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libvlccore5 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be    installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas? I am using ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently upon looking, `vlc-data` was still installed on the system. Even after running:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc
```

and

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc*
```

No idea why this happened.

I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc-data
```

I then disabled the PPA for VLC, and installed the one in the standard repository. Then I re-enabled the source and was able to update to 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me also with ppa:n-muench/vlc

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable third-party repositories. Maybe the Sopcast player repositories are to blame.

Comment: I disabled 'Independent' and still no luck.
some other media sources I have are KdenLive, miro, and handbrake. Would any of thous cause a problem?

Comment: Yes.
Just disable all sources of PPA.
And do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: ok, so i disabled everything but main, and universe.
and it is still not working:

e following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore5 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.0.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

Purge it from your computer and then re-install it.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc
```

Once that is done install it again.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: It says that vlc is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/vlc2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

for Mint 17 & 17.1