# Lost vlc after a partial upgrade - cannot reinstall due to unmet dependencies

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, vlc

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and run a partial upgrade via Update Manager.
This resulted in removing VLC.

I've tried reinstalling using `sudo apt-get install vlc` but got this error:

```
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
 been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
 resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:  vlc : Depends:  
 vlc-nox (= 3.0.0~~git20141202+r58827+31~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not
 going to be installed  
        Depends: libavutil53 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable  
        Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.0~~git20141202+r58827+31~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed  
        Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.0~~git20141202+r58827+31~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
 packages.
```

I've tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197161/cant-reinstall-vlc) (purging vlc) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163043/unable-to-re-install-vlc-after-a-partial-upgrade-12-04-due-to-broken-packages) (adding the stable-daily ppa) but none of them worked, still getting the same error.

What can I do now?

**Updates**

1. Tried `sudo apt-get install -f` and then installing vlc, still the same results.
2. Tried the solution from the other question, and after trying several suggestions with no succes, I selected the one that offered to install the most of the packages. VLC was installed **but not properly**, as I am getting this error now

   `VLC media player 3.0.0-git Vetinari (revision 3.0.0~~git20141202+r58827+31~ubuntu14.04.1)
   [000000000243c118] core libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.`

Comment: Okay, `sudo apt-get install -f` might help.

Comment: @Tim It didn't help, still got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for "ubuntu partial upgrade via Update Manager" and I found this, it sounds relevant though it's "mainly for those of us that run a development version of Ubuntu" and it's probably not an answer you're looking for : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/partialupgrade

Here's the headlines:

Contents

1. What to do when offered a partial upgrade

   1. I'm offered a partial upgrade, what should I do?
   2. Summary or "I don't really care if I keep messing things up and wasting my and others' time with preventable problems, and you have 30 seconds to convince me to care!"
   3. Short Version or "Hmm, so I shouldn't blindly do "Partial Upgrade"s and dist-upgrade? I didn't know that..."
   4. Long Version or "I want to be a better tester! I care! Tell me more!"

Comment: Damn, this is a great wiki post! :P

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve it by using y-ppa-manager.

This were the steps I took:

1. Removing duplicate ppas (just to be sure)
2. Manage PPAs > Purged all the vlc relevant PPAs (there where 3)
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade`
5. `sudo aptitude install vlc`

and I finally have my vlc back again and running.